# make an object exclude a light source in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, lighting

I have a spot light behind a treeline image to project the shadows.. but I don't want the spot light to affect the house or anything else.. I saw many posts saying that selective lighting is not possible in cycles. Is there ant tricks or other ways to get this done ? I just need the shadow of treeline without the light effecting the entire scene :) thankyou

[image: ht]

Comment: Use a shadow catcher: have a copy of the geometry that receives the shadow in a different layer as well as the light and objects that are projecting those shadows. Set the receiving geometry as  shadow catcher and combine the different layers in the compositor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If no lights affect your house, how is it going to be lit?
You got 3 choices:

Go to properties>Object>Cycles settings and uncheck SHADOWS (your object cannot cast or recieve shadows) try find what works for you.

Second choice: Use EXCLUDE layers on the PASS LAyer system (that requires a little bit of knowledge on how to exclude things) -again, if you exclude the house, it will appear in your render totally black since no lights lit the object.

Road 3: Setup a LIGHT PATH shader node to exclude to recieve any lights or cast shadow on the object. Have a "per shader per object" override material ready before render. This also requires a bit of work on your side.

(Light emission with a shader / unlit object):
[image]

But hey, these are the possibilities.
Thanks if you vote me up as Answer.

BFCT_Schiller

Comment: Thankyou for your suggestions :) By the way I used HDR lighting in  the scene .. And to show the treeline in the bright HDR lit environment.. The spotlight behind the treeline had to be really bright.. Which affected the whole scene